# Insert event with Google Calendar API in Chrome Extension keeps failing

Tags: google-chrome-extension, insert, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I'm having trouble getting the format right for a chrome extension using the Google Calendar API.  I have an OAuth2 access token (which is valid, I can test that with tokenInfo), but am having trouble.  I'm using a proprietary framework to build the extension, which complicates things, but maybe you could help me find out what information I'm missing:

```
var eventParams = e.data,
    request = {
      'method' : 'POST',
      'async'  : true,
      'url':   'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'+CAL_ID + '/events',
      'headers': {
        'Authorization' : TOKEN
      },
      'params': eventParams
    };
```

My token looks like this:

```
{↵ "issued_to": "831101123055-874tukfvuvkma6s0l7m70iqlc3lirnkc.apps.googleusercontent.com",↵ "audience": "831101123055-874tukfvuvkma6s0l7m70iqlc3lirnkc.apps.googleusercontent.com",↵ "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",↵ "expires_in": 3600,↵ "access_type": "offline"↵}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

I'm not really sure why that's the case, because my request is authenticated.  Am I not passing the token correctly?  Someone has suggested that I need to include an API key, but my understanding is that API keys are only for apps requiring public access and don't need access to user data, and that OAuth2 takes the place of an API key.

I'd appreciate any help you guys can offer!  Thank you!

Comment: Use chrome.identity api instead.

Comment: Zig, the framework I'm using makes using the chrome.identity api very difficult.  There must be a way to do this with XMLHTTPRequest intuitively--can you help me with that, per my question? Besides, like I mentioned, the problem is with the insert API, not getting an OAuth token.  I've taken care of that already.

Thank you for the suggestion, but that won't work for my purposes.

Comment: ive implemented oauth from an extension before, but removed the code once identity api was available. My code did the entire flow, not just using the token. Look at the old extension oauth examples, I did have to modify a bit of it to handle all the errors like revoked token.

Comment: I'd be thrilled if I could even _get_ to error handling--right now I'm just trying to make a basic API call with an authenticated token and am repeatedly failing.

Comment: see the sample I mention https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the error was kind of anomalous, the problem turned out to be with the data type.  The correct syntax was:

```
var eventParams = e.data,
  request = {
    'method' : 'POST',
    'async'  : true,
    'url':   'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' + CAL_ID + '/events',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization' : TOKEN_TYPE+' '+ TOKEN,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    'contentType': 'json',
    'params': JSON.stringify(eventParams)
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have calendar API enabled in the developers console:
https://console.developers.google.com

Comment: Hi Luc, thanks, I checked and it is enabled.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please first try the link Zig recommended and make sure you are getting the correct token. The only other thing I can think of is missing https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly scope.